# App_Code folder: the source of problems

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I created a new Handler class which I placed in the App_Code folder afterwards. In Visual Studio everything seemed fine but while debbuging, the browser window was returning the error:

> Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'Microsoft.Build' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member....

The solution was to remove the class file from the App_Code folder. Uppon testing, I also noticed that whenever I was creating a new Class in the App_Code folder, code Auto-Complete was not working.

Does anyone know a possible source of this error behaviour?

Comment: `App_Code` is kind of legacy and has a lot of specific features - used in `WebSite` projects (also kind of legacy project type, had so many problematic issues).

Are you aware of these and sure of what are you trying to do?

Comment: I dissagree with Dusan - anyway, your issue is probably because the web server did not recognize the chnages, try to make a change on the page that you work, to signal web server that there are changes to see... also there are some flags for optimazions on web.config that maybe are open and thats why its fail to see the changes on code. A better way is to make a custom library project (.dll) with all your function

Comment: Well, you can disagree, but the `Web Site` project definutelly goes to history: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
I have a question for you - have you ever used a `Web Site` project?

Comment: When you add new class to `App_Code` folder,  right click on class, go to properties, and set `Build Action= Compile`